# Python - Dynamic selection of columns to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, widget, ipywidgets, streamlit

I am looking for a solution to dynamically select two columns from a dataframe (using ipywidgets or steamlit for example) and create a new dataframe using that selection.

The aim is to allow a user to select two columns from a larger dataset to allow filtering of those two columns to remove NaNs for regression and plotting. I do not want to type every column header out as the dataframe will change for every use. Any help would be of much help!

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,NaN], 'B' : [10,20], 'C' : [100,50], 'D' : [-30,-50]})

x_choice = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(df.select_dtypes('number').columns)[0:],
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,
)

y_choice = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(df.select_dtypes('number').columns)[1:],
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,
)


dfX = pd.DataFrame(x_choice, y_choice)
dfX.dropna()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is using the streamlit approach. Frame is styled to look it better when displayed using st.dataframe() but you can ignore it.

#### Code

```
"""
Creates a new datafame based on selected column from existing dataframe.
"""

import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 


df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,None], 'B' : [10,20],
                   'C' : [100,50], 'D' : [-30,-50],
                   'E' : [1500,800], 'F' : [0.258,1.366]})

# Apply styler so that the A column will be displayed with integer value because there is None in it.
df_style = df.style.format(precision=2, na_rep='MISSING', thousands=",", formatter={('A'): "{:.0f}"})

st.write('Current dataframe')
st.dataframe(df_style)

# We use a form to wait for the user to finish selecting columns.
# The user would press the submit button when done.
# This is done to optimize the streamlit application performance.
# As we know streamlit will re-run the code from top to bottom
# whenever the user changes the column selections.
with st.form('form'):
    sel_column = st.multiselect('Select column', df.columns,
       help='Select a column to form a new dataframe. Press submit when done.')
    drop_na = st.checkbox('Drop rows with missing value', value=True)
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
    
if submitted:
    dfnew = df[sel_column]
    if drop_na:
        dfnew = dfnew.dropna()

    st.write('New dataframe')
    dfnew_style = dfnew.style.format(precision=2, na_rep='MISSING', thousands=",", formatter={('A'): "{:.0f}"})
    st.dataframe(dfnew_style)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: That works incredibly well thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is to create a different callback function for each of the dropdowns and create a new dataframe inside each of these functions that only keeps the columns selected by the dropdowns.

See code below:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [4,10], 'B' : [10,20], 'C' : [100,50], 'D' : [-30,-50]})

x_choice = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(df.select_dtypes('number').columns)[0:],
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,
)

y_choice = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(df.select_dtypes('number').columns)[1:],
    description='Number:',
    disabled=False,
)

def update_dropdown_x(change):

    df_new = df[[change.new,y_choice.value]].copy()
    print(df_new)


def update_dropdown_y(change):

    df_new = df[[x_choice.value,change.new]].copy()
    print(df_new)


x_choice.observe(update_dropdown_x,names='value')
y_choice.observe(update_dropdown_y,names='value')

display(x_choice,y_choice)
```

And below is an example of the variable `df_new` after selecting columns `B` and `C`:

```
    B    C
0  10  100
1  20   50
```

`C` and `D`:

```
     C   D
0  100 -30
1   50 -50
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I am curious how to apply a df.dropna() after this. Tried applying it throughout but did not seem to change anything